# As an allegory, what is implied by 《三打白骨精》

Tags: phrase-meaning

A girl asked me to help translate her introduction. I'm wondering, what is implied by 《三打白骨精》? Is this phrase used as an allegory or metaphor?

《西游记》想必都是大家的童年回忆,
Journey to the West must be a childhood memory for all of us,
《三打白骨精》更是最经典的场景之一，
The scene "Three blows to the White Bone Spirit" is perhaps one of the most classic scenes in the book,
今天我们将以喜剧的形式又重现在舞台上，
today, in comedy form, we will make this scene reappear on stage,
接下来请欣赏话剧《三打白骨精》
please enjoy the following play "Three blows to the White Bone Spirit."

Comment: So, why can't it just be a scene, as introduced by this girl? It's actually just a chapter (part) of the novel 西游记。

Comment: http://www.sohu.com/a/233864061_100168412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's any special implication. I bet it's just a fun story to watch, as it involves a beautiful female demon(妖精) trying to eat the monk(唐僧)'s meat to achieve immortality.

However, 白骨精 does have a modern interpretation which is short for 白领 + 骨干 + 精英, which is not related to this, but does (usually) refer to beautiful women, who are white collar elite worker, with high level education and income. Refer to definition here: [Baidu](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%99%BD%E9%AA%A8%E7%B2%BE/16269738)